# Synchronized / connected side-by-side video jupyter notebook

Tags: video, synchronization, jupyter

I am working on a side-by-side visualization of two animations that I display using the HTML function. Rather than autolooping it for the whole time, I would like to be able to use the slider to navigate through the frames. Unfortunately, I am not able to synchronize both sliders. Specifically, when I move to Frame XY in side-by-side video one, this should happen automatically in side-by-side video two. And the other way around. Any idea for this?

My code for displaying both videos for now is:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import Video

SalidaEjes = widgets.Output()

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)

with SalidaEjes:
    display(HTML(animation_video_1))


SalidaVideo = widgets.Output()

with SalidaVideo:
    display(HTML(animation_video_2))

Salidas = widgets.HBox([SalidaEjes, SalidaVideo])
display(Salidas)
```

In my case, both videos have different sizes. Can I adjust the videos to have the same display-size after the animations being already created?
Thanks for helping me out.